# Perl DBI - Getting records affected of each statement in a transaction

Tags: database, perl, transactions, dbi

HI,

I use perl DBI do() which will execute the below SQL block like below which executes in SQL SERVER 2005

> ```
>     eval {
>             my $result =  do(<<SQL);
>             BEGIN TRAN
>
>             UPDATE table1 SET
>             col1 = 999 where date = '2010-08-27'
>
>             DELETE FROM table1
>             where date = '2010-08-30'
>
>             COMMIT TRAN
> SQL
>     $logger->info($result);
> };
> ```

Now i can see that the return value $result only contains the rows affected by the first update statement.So i dont have any information about the deleted rows , But i can see that the rows are indeed deleted in the Database.

In general if i have a INSERT , DELETE , UPDATE statement inside a BEGIN TRAN , COMMIT TRAN block and if the entire block will be submitted by DBI do() method , I would need to know the exact number of statements inserted , number of statements updated and number of statements deleted.

I know that SQL SERVER's @@ROWCOUNT will give me the rows affected after each statement , but that is a SQL server variable which will be visible only inside the block. Is it possible to get the data into perl ?

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of `@@ROWCOUNT`, you need to add `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT 'rowcount'` as the last command before "COMMIT TRAN", then the whole SQL will return the result set consising of 1 row with 1 'rowcount' column.

The only caveat is that since `do()` method doesn't provide you with results sets, you need to switch to `prepare()/fetchrow_array()/fetchrow_array()` instead, or use one of the wrapper methods like `nsql()` from your DB library if those are available.

For a detailed inserted/updated/deleted breakdown, simply save those @@ROWCOUNTs into variables after the insert/update/delete, and select the counts afterwards:

```
declare @update_count int
declare @delete_count int

UPDATE table1 SET
col1 = 999 where date = '2010-08-27'
SELECT @update_count = @@ROWCOUNT

DELETE FROM table1
where date = '2010-08-30'
SELECT @delete_count = @@ROWCOUNT

SELECT @update_count 'update_count', @delete_count '@delete_count'
```

Answer (score 1):

What database access method is in use? Is there any reason for not moving the transaction logic outside of the T-SQL?

If you're using DBI something along these lines should satisfy your requirements:

```
eval {
    $dbh->begin_work;
        $dbh->do("CREATE TABLE #temp (col1 INTEGER, date DATETIME);");

        # Inserts
        my $inserted = $dbh->do("INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1,'2010-08-27');");
        $inserted += $dbh->do("INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 999,'2010-08-27' UNION SELECT 5, '2010-08-30';");

        # Updates
        my $updated = $dbh->do("UPDATE #temp SET col1 = 999 WHERE date = '2010-08-27';");

        # Deleted
        my $deleted = $dbh->do("DELETE FROM #temp WHERE date = '2010-08-30';");
    $dbh->commit;

    print "Inserted $inserted rows.\n";
    print "Updated $updated rows.\n";
    print "Deleted $deleted rows.\n"; }
```

This snippet doesn't take into account making the database connection, error handling, or closing the connection, but DBI documentation should help there. http://metacpan.org/pod/DBI

You probably also want to look into the prepare and bind_param DBI methods if you're planning on executing multiple non-select statements.

Comment: I have a whole lot of INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE to run as a single transaction. i.e why i need to have all the statements inside a T-SQL BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN block. So the only way i can think is to have the entire SQL as a string , prepare() it ,execute and fetch return results which will have the counts. Will having multiple do's inside a begin_work and commit as you have written give the same effect. Is is entirely ACID ?

Comment: Yes, having the multiple do statements between the begin_work and rollback/commit will have the same effect as a BEGIN TRANSACTION and ROLLBACK TRANSACTION/COMMIT TRANSACTION block in T-SQL. You can test this behavior by replacing $dbh->begin_work with $dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;, then adding commits and rollbacks after the different DML operations. The prints will show the number of rows affected no matter if the transaction was rolled back or committed, but dumping table results should show expected data.